# arangodb AQL use memory

Tags: arangodb

I want to know how much memory an AQL query needs, I use a cluster of 3 nodes,
I have two collections, one is a collection of points and the other is a collection of edges, Each collection has 6 shards,
Point collection index size is 33.8GB, Edge index size is 284GB.